# How can I 'print' an HTML form to words?

Tags: html, forms, ms-word

I'm doing a project for my department that consist of converting a word report to an online platform (HTML Form)

The form "Criminal Event Report" needs to be filled in an html form, and then we need to run a function that will output it in a Word document to specific fields.

Any ideas on how that could be achieved ? We're using Bootstrap 4 html for Front-end, JS / Python in back-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using JS and Python both to save your form data to Word document.
Refer
Python : *https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-working-with-docx-module/* 
JS : *https://docx.js.org/*